# Model first junction table using foreign keys as composite primary key?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-model-first

I have a `Job` table and a `Contact` table, I need to create another table `JobContact` to allow many to many, but I want the `JobId` and `ContactId` to be used as its primary key.

I need it on the designer so I can add additional columns to it.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case you must create new `JobContact` entity in the designer and mark `JobId` and `ContactId` as entity keys. After that you can add additional properties to this entity and create one-to-many relation with `Job` and `Contact` entities.